# Audit Trail from Logs

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make an Audit Trail in .NET Framework. My application is logging lot of stuff to AWS logs already. But I want to track all actions from those logs and want to present them in a user-friendly way on UI to showcase what happened and when. That means what action was taken first and what timing.
The log is basically a technical record which has Request URL, Response URL, data payload sent, timestamp.
But I want to read it and present it in a way that a normal user can understand the action.
For ex:
Requested : List of User Tax Returns, Time:hh:mm:ss, Date: mm/dd/yyyy